# How to upload csv file from frontend to s3 in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is what happen in frontend(Reactjs).
The csv file will be stored at this.state.excelFile after browsing.

Upload.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class User extends Component {

    state = {
       excelFile:''
    }

     getFileDetail = (event) =>{
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(file)
        this.setState({excelFile:File})
    }

    uploadFile = async() =>{
        // API call to pass this.state.excelFile in body
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <section className="section auth">
                <div className="container">
                    <input type="file" onChange={(event) =>{this.getFileDetail(event)}}></input>
                    <input type='submit' value="Upload" onClick={()=>{this.uploadFile()}}></input>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

this.state.excelFile will look like this.
[image]

This is the lambda function in nodejs to upload csv file to s3.

UploadToS3.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const fileType = require('file-type');
const sha1 = require('sha1');

exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {

    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode = 0;

    const { base64String }  = JSON.parse(event.body);

    let buffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');
    
    // fileMime = undefined here
    let fileMime = await fileType.fromBuffer(buffer);

    // check if the base64 encoded string is a file
    if (fileMime === null) {
        return context.fail('The string supplied is not a file type');
    }

    let file = getFile(fileMime, buffer);

    let params = file.params;

    let hashId = file.uploadFile.name
    try{
        const data = await s3.upload(params).promise();
        data.s3Key = hashId
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(data);
        statusCode = 201;
    }catch(err){
        responseBody = `Unable to create Banners in S3: ${err}`;
        statusCode = 403;
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        },
        body: responseBody
    }

    return response
};

let getFile = function (fileMime, buffer) {
    
    let hash = sha1(Buffer.from(new Date().toString()));

    let fileFullPath = 'https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/myBucket/banners/';

    let fileName =  hash;
    let params = {
        Bucket: 'myBucket',
        Key: 'banners/' + fileName,
        Body: buffer,
        ContentType: fileMime.mime,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    let uploadFile = {
        size: buffer.toString('ascii').length,
        type: fileMime.mime,
        name: fileName,
        full_path: fileFullPath
    }

    return {
        'params': params,
        'uploadFile': uploadFile
    }
}
```

I tried to convert my csv file to base64 through below base64 converter and then test the lambda function.

https://www.browserling.com/tools/file-to-base64

But below variable return undefined

```
let fileMime = await fileType.fromBuffer(buffer);
```

So I was wondering if I should turn this.state.excelFile to base64 in frontend,
Or I should modify my nodejs function instead